# 9 patch fill area not working with multiple scale areas

Tags: android, nine-patch

In my 9 patch I've added a fill area to be the contents taking most of the width and from below the red rectangle. However as the scale images show it's not working. If I remove the scale area shown by the arrow then it works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong or not understanding about 9 patch?

Thanks.

[image: 9 patch image scale section not filling properly]

Comment: is it valid to stretch two areas along the same side? http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Scaling is proportional to how many pixels you use on the side. Your top area uses 3 pixels and bottom area uses ~24 pixels, so the bottom area will stretch 8x more than the top. If you want them to stretch equally, they need to be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I found a related answer that explains it perfectly for me:

- [Android nine-patch content-border not honoured](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20962766/383414)

> The content region is defined by the right and lower bars as mentioned
>   above, but **what you are really defining is the padding**
>   (top,left,bottom and right padding).

So think of it in terms of "padding" around the content area, as defined by the white pixels.

Check out the linked answer for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is your image,but I think it is better to exclude the red rectangle from image.
Then use a layout and put your background image, for its background,
and add Image element in that layout for displaying your red rectangle.