# Android nine-patch content-border not honoured

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a 9-patch image. I defined top left quadrant to be a content area, yet it is not honoured (see the preview on the right hand side of the screenshot). What am I missing? Thanks!

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 3):

The content region is defined by the right and lower bars as mentioned above, but **what you are really defining is the padding** (top,left,bottom and right padding).

The padding is set by counting the number of transparent pixels at the start and end of the right and lower bars.  So the padding would be approx 10,10,40,40 (t,l,b,r) if your image was 100x100.

*When the image is stretched, the padding doesn't change and since it is measure from each edge, that explains why the content area stretches the way it does.*

Comment: Thanks. You are correct and I confirmed it. Padding size (actual size - content size) stays the same regardless of how the image is stretched.

Comment: "what you are really defining is the padding" - That is the key to this issue. Your point of view inverts how I have viewed the content area definition and I believe this is key to many related questions.

Answer (score -1):

Your content area, defined by the right and lower black bars, is fully contained in the stretchable region, defined by the upper and left black bars. Hence the content region will also be stretched, this is intended.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. If both stretchable region and content region are scaled up/down, it shouldn't affect the outcome, should it?

for instance, if the original image were 100x100, and the content region were 40x40, and the image were scaled down to 50%, image size would be 50x50. yet the content size is not 20x20 - in my case, it becomes much smaller than 20x20.